# References in a table

Tags: database

I have a table like this, that contains items that are added to the database.

**Catalog table example**

```
id | element | catalog  
0  | mazda   | car  
1  | penguin | animal  
2  | zebra   | animal
```

etc....

And then I have a table where the user selects items from that table, and I keep a reference of what has been selected like this

**User table example**

```
id | name | age | itemsSelected  
0  | john | 18  | 2;3;7;9
```

So what I am trying to say, is that I keep a reference to what the user has selected as a string if ID's, but I think this seems a tad troublesome

Because when I do a query to get information about a user, all I get is the string of `2;3;7;9`, when what I really want is an array of the items corresponing to those ID's

Right now I get the ID's and I have to split the string, and then run another query to find the elements the ID's correspond to

Is there any easier ways to do this, if my question is understandable?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way to do this. You create a third table which contains a map of A/B. It's called a *Multiple to Multiple foreign-key relationship.*

You have your *Catalogue* table `(int, varchar(MAX), varchar(MAX))` or similar.

You have your *User* table `(int, varchar(MAX), varchar(MAX), varchar(MAX))` or similar, essentially, remove the last column and then create another table:

You create a *UserCatalogue* table: `(int UserId, int CatalogueId)` with a `Primary Key` on both columns. Then the **UserId** column gets a Foreign-Key to `User.Id`, and the **CatalogueId** table gets a Foreign-Key to `Catalogue.Id`. This preserves the relationship and eases queries. It also means that if `Catalogue.Id` number 22 does not exist, you cannot accidentally insert it as a relation between the two. *This is called referential-integrity.* The SQL Server mandates that if you say, "*This* column **must** have a reference to *this other* table" then the SQL Server will mandate that *relationship*.

After you create this, for each `itemsSelected` you add an entry: I.e.

```
UserId | CatalogueId
0      | 2
0      | 3
0      | 7
0      | 9
```

This also alows you to use `JOIN`s on the tables for *faster* queries.

---

Additionally, and unrelated to the question, you can also optimize the `Catalogue` table you have a bit, and create another table for `CatalogueGroup`, which contains your last column there (`catalog`: *car*, *animal*) which is referenced via a *Foreign-Key Relationship* in the current `Catalogue` table definition you have. This will also ***save*** storage space and speed up SQL Server work, as it no longer has to read a `string` column if you only want the `element` value.